# @TableGenerator for mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I've used with success @TableGenerator with EclipseLink:

```
@Id
@TableGenerator(name = "ID_GEN",
        table = "seq",
        pkColumnName = "seqName",
        valueColumnName = "`id`",
        pkColumnValue = "SEQUENCE")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "ID_GEN")
private Long id;
```

I was searching if there is an equivalent possibility for Mybatis to accomplish the same result but the only thing I see is some reference to generatedKey:

http://www.mybatis.org/generator/configreference/generatedKey.html#)

The statement below(from above link) is referring to some possible "sequences" which makes me think that there might be a way to use the same kind of sequence table to accomplish this.

"The  element is used to specify properties for auto generated keys (from identity field or sequences)."

Is there any way to use this @GeneratedValue/@TableGenerator mechanism in Mybatis?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`@TableGenerator` is the feature of JPA. Under the hood JPA implementation issues multiple queries to generate the value. mybatis does not do this, that is it does not execute any queries you did not specify explicitly, so there is no simple and declarative way to achieve the same functionality as `@TableGenerator` provides. You will need to emulate the queries the hibernate does to the sequence table.

In mybatis you can use `selectKey` to generate the value.

Here is slightly modified example from the [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#select) that emulates `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` strategy:

```
<insert id="insertAuthor">
  <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="int" order="BEFORE">
    select nextval('author_id_seq') 
  </selectKey>
  insert into Author
    (id, username, password, email,bio, favourite_section)
  values
    (#{id}, #{username}, #{password}, #{email}, #{bio}, #{favouriteSection,jdbcType=VARCHAR})
</insert>
```

In `selectKey` section the arbitrary query may be specified. It's result will be assigned to the property specified in `keyProperty` in this case `id` of the passed object.

The actual query to emulate `@TableGenerator` strategy `GenerationType.TABLE` depends on the database. For postgresql the query in `selectKey` would be something like:

```
INSERT INTO seq (seqName, id) values ('SEQUENCE', 1)
ON CONFLICT
 DO UPDATE id = id + 1
 WHERE seqName = 'SEQUENCE'
RETURNING id
```

Comment: This solution takes the id from the database and increments it.
The example I provide from Eclipse Link is using @TableGenerator with a sequence table(see table = "seq"). That tables contains the sequence  name, the id and some block size(More details about this method on chapter 3.4: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers).

Comment: Any sql select query can be used in `selectKey`. The actual query to use (if possible at all) depends on the db you are using.

Comment: According to this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-never-use-the-table-identifier-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), `GenerationType.TABLE` is achieved by executing multiple SQLs under the hood. If that actually is the case, there is no comparable feature in MyBatis and you may need to implement it yourself. @RomanKonoval's answer corresponds to `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`. For `GenerationType.IDENTITY`, there is `useGeneratedKeys` option.

Comment: Yes. It seems GenerationType.TABLE cannot be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've implemented a custom id generator sequence manager to achieve GenerationType.TABLE behavior in mybatis:

```
@Mapper
public interface ReadOnly {

    @Select("SELECT `index` from sequence WHERE sequenceName = #{sequenceName}")
    Long getNextIndex(@Param("sequenceName") String sequenceName);
}

@Mapper
public interface ReadWrite {

    @Update("UPDATE sequence SET `index` = #{index} WHERE (sequenceName = #{sequenceName})")
    void updateIndex(@Param("index") long index, @Param("sequenceName") String sequenceName);


@Component
public class SequenceManager {

    @Autowired
    ReadOnly readonly;

    @Autowired
    ReadWrite readwrite;

    private long index = 0;

    private static long blockSize = 10;

    public SequenceManager() {
    }

    public long getNextIndex(String sequenceName) {
        if (index % blockSize == 0) {
            index = getAfterIncrement(sequenceName);
        }
        return index++;
    }

    @Transactional
    public long getAfterIncrement(String sequenceName) {
        index = readonly.getNextIndex(sequenceName);
        readwrite.updateIndex(index + blockSize, sequenceName);
        return index + blockSize;
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone helping with this one.